# Is there a way to Re update the table in SQL after the data is inserted in MS sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I would like to update the table CustBill by adding the amount of same bill Id and picking up earliest date from Duedate

This is the table that is after inserting the data

```
Bill ID    Amount   CUstName   Duedate    
12         12.2     ABC        12222016
12         22.2     ABC        12112016
13         23.22    ABC        12102016
```

This is how my table should be updated after insertion of data

```
Bill ID    Amount   CUstName   Duedate
12         34.4     ABC        12112016
13         23.22    ABC        12102016
```

How to do this?

Comment: You can google for triggers after insert
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39970/sql-server-after-insert-trigger

Comment: Your goal is not entirely clear. Is the goal to aggregate amounts of whatever is inserted? How do you come up with the DueDate? Why should it be the earliest DueDate, if the first entry allows for payment on Dec 22nd?

Comment: If the two rows for bill_id 12 have different DueDates,why would you want to aggregate them?

Comment: @roy.d- you mean DML triggers? like Update and all ? so will I be able to do this with triggers with out creating temp tables or other stored procedures or tables?

Comment: @SchmitzIT and Andrew - sorry for the confusion, I would ike to pick the earliest date

Comment: @linkin But why? That doesn't make sense from a financial point of view

Comment: @SchmitzIT - the data I have is in this format and I am trying to find a solution for that, Let me know if you can suggest any tech solutions for it

Comment: I am not sure of your exact requirements, but if it was me doing it, I would not want to lose the individual records. I would instead just create a view that aggregated the component parts, e.g `CREATE VIEW dbo.SomeView AS SELECT BillID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount, CUstName, MIN(DueDate) AS Duedate FROM SomeTable GROUP BY BillID, CustName;`. This way, if there is every any confusion about how you have arrived at a certain due date or amount, you have the original records to help you debug.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `After INSERT Trigger` like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[myUpdateTriggerAfterInsert]
ON  [dbo].[myTable]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @DueDate as Datetime;
DECLARE @CUstName as varchar(max);
DECLARE @Amount as decimal(15,0);
DECLARE @BillId as int;

SET @BillId = (SELECT [Bill Id] FROM inserted);
SET @DueDate = (SELECT TOP 1 [Duedate] FROM [dbo].[myTable] WHERE [Bill Id] = @BillId ORDER BY [Duedate] ASC);
SET @CUstName = (SELECT [CUstName] FROM inserted);
SET @Amount = (SELECT SUM([Amount]) FROM [dbo].[myTable] WHERE [Bill Id] = @BillId GROUP BY [Bill Id]);

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[myTable] WHERE [Bill Id] = @BillId) > 1
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM [dbo].[myTable] WHERE [Bill Id] = @BillId;
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[myTable] ([Bill Id], [CUstName], [Amount], [DueDate])
    VALUES (@BillId, @CUstName, @Amount, @DueDate);
END
END
```

Also make sure `CUstName` is always the same for a given `Bill Id` or you might lose information.

Comment: Thanks for your help, After doing INSERT INTO mytable, I have added your solution to the stored procedure and I am getting this error- This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
Error #1 Message: The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Try the following sentence, then check sentence by sentence the rest of the answer to find out your issue. `DECLARE @DueDate as Datetime;
DECLARE @CUstName as varchar(max);
DECLARE @Amount as decimal(15,0);
DECLARE @BillId as int;

SET @BillId = 123;
SET @DueDate = 12/06/2017;
SET @CUstName = 'customer';
SET @Amount = 20.0;

IF 2 > 1 BEGIN;SELECT 1;END`